# iOS : GMSPlacePickerViewController Country Restriction

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

[image]For Place selection inside the iOS app we are using "**GMSPlacePickerViewController**".  This display by default a search bar for place selection. How can we restrict places to be search for specific countries ? I need South Africa location only.

I know that "**GMSAutocompleteFilter**" allow to filter but how can we set this with "**GMSPlacePickerViewController**" ?

Is there any option we can customise UI with GMSPlacePickerViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to restrict your search to India

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.city
filter.country = "india"
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, I know about this but question is How to use GMSAutocompleteFilter  with GMSPlacePickerViewController ?

Comment: Hi Mangesh. Let me research and get back to you.